# Sending data to the controller with button_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is the button:

```
<%= button_to "I want to understand this.", articles_want_to_understand_path, :id => @article.id, method: :post %>
```

This is the controller code:

```
def want_to_understand
  @article.user_who_wants_to_understand << current_user
  redirect_to action: :show
end

private

def set_article
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
end
```

This is the error:

```
undefined method `user_who_wants_to_understand' for nil:NilClass
```

Comment: That's not the problem, the problem is "for nil:NilClass", which means the controller doesn't find the article. If I replace @article with Article.first it doesn't throw that error.

Comment: Use `articles_want_to_understand_path(id: @article.id)` instead.

Comment: Still get the same error.

Comment: Turns out I had to paste the content of set_article into want_to_understand.

Comment: Did it work that way? you could also use a before_ callback.

Answer (score 0):

in your controller : -

```
before_action :set_article, only: [:want_to_understand]
def want_to_understand
  @article.user_who_wants_to_understand << current_user
  redirect_to action: :show
end

private

def set_article
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
end
```

and in your view page: -

```
<%= button_to "I want to understand this.", articles_want_to_understand_path(id: @article.id) %>
```

A side note : with button to convert into html form and form by default is of post type so you don't need to specify method type post for your routes which is of post type.